# When running a terminal, I get the default bash prompt

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Whenever I run a terminal in Linux (Centos), my console line starts with:

```
bash-4.1$
```

During the Centos installation, I created a user 'mark'. Later on that day, I needed to change the name to 'john' for some reason.

So I went into these files and changed 'mark' to 'john'

```
/etc/passwd 
/etc/group
/etc/shadow
mv mark john
```

After a restart, I'm now getting the `bash-4.1$` prompt on the terminal.

Comment: Read the `usermod` and `groupmod` manpages, `man bash` will be useful too. Check the startup scripts section.

Comment: My guess is that you didn't rename your home directory from `/home/mark` to `/home/john`.  And so you have no profile configuration.

Comment: @Zoredache exactly what I thought. Might need to ensure his permissions will allow him to read the folder if he chooses to rename it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what things you edited in the mentioned files. Probably, as Zoredache mentioned, you forgot to change the `/home/mark` to `/home/john` either in the passwd or on the filesystem. Also there is an entry in passwd which tells the default shell for the user.

You can also set default shell of existing user by `usermod -s <path to shell> <username>` command.

Comment: CentOS recommends `chsh` for shell change.